# How can I prove path connected components an connected components are the same?

Tags: general-topology

$X$ is locally path connected. I want to prove that connected components and path components of $X$ are the "same". How can I do that?

Comment: Hint: Show that path components are open and observe that this immediately implies that they are closed, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be a path-component of $X$. Let $x \in P$. Then let $U_x$ be a path-connected neighbourhood of $x$ (which exists). Then $U_x \cup P$ is path-connected: the only case to check is when $a \in U_x$, $b \in P$ (or vice versa), then combine a path $p_1$ from $a$ to $x$ (in the path-connected $U_x$) with a path $p_2$ from $x$ to $b$ in $P$ (in the usual way: $p_1(2t)$ for $0 \le t \le \frac{1}{2}$ and $p_2(1-2t)$ for $\frac{1}{2} \le t \le 1$).

As $P$ is maximally path conencted, $U_x \cup P = P$, and so $U_x \subseteq P$, showing that $P$ is open.

As $X = \cup_i P_i$ is a disjoint union of path-components and all $P_i$ are open, all $P_i$ are closed too (their complements are unions of open, so open). And if $C$ is a connected subset, it must be contained in one $P_i$, or this union would disconnect $C$. So the components are exactly the path components (which are certainly connected, so contained in a component, but they cannot be bigger than a $P_i$ by the above).

Comment: See also https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+path-connected+space#properties